# Keyboard entry to integer java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm attempting to turn a keyboard entry into an integer, but my program keeps crashing. 
It works when the a character such as "k" is entered but crashes when I enter "5".
Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
// Getting an integer value.
public static int getInt() {
    int numberEntered = 0;
    String entry = "";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        entry = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("That is not an integer.  " + "Please try again.");
    }
    numberEntered = Integer.parseInt(entry);
    System.out.print(numberEntered);
    return numberEntered;
}
```

Output:

```
Error given: k That is not an integer. 
Please try again. 
8 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "k" at 
  java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) 
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652) 
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770) 
    at Program2.getInt(Program2.java:56) 
    at Program2.problemSelectionMenu(Program2.java:40) 
    at Program2.main(Program2.java:14)
```

Comment: `Attempting to turn a keyboard entry into an integer and it crashes.` - define "crashes". Do you get an Exception of some kind? Post the error message. Also post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. That is show us the class that invokes the method so we understand the context of how the method is used. We should be able to compile/test whatever you post.

Comment: Error given: k
That is not an integer.  Please try again.
8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "k"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
 at Program2.getInt(Program2.java:56)
 at Program2.problemSelectionMenu(Program2.java:40)
 at Program2.main(Program2.java:14)

Comment: Put the information related to the question in the question, not in the comment so all the information related to the question is found in one place and also it will be formatted and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check to make sure that the input has a next int, but then once the `Scanner` has a next int, you never resolve the int to `entry`, so it is still the bad input. You need to assign the `int` entered by the user to `entry`. You can do this very easily by just calling [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()):

```
while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
    entry = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("That is not an integer.  " + "Please try again.");
}
numberEntered = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.print(numberEntered);
return numberEntered;
```

Answer (score 1):

when you are giving character as an input, while loop condition is true so it goes in while loop and scan the character and print value of character but when you give integer then in while loop condition becomes false and it does not go in the while loop. out of the while  loop you are parsing the integer,you don't need to do that because you are taking integer as input.all you have to do is that at the place of 
   integer.parseInt(entry)  ,you have to scan the integer i.e.
    int i =keyboard.nextInt(); 
beacuase in the while loop condition you are only checking that the input you have  given is integer or not. but you have not scan the input in case of integer.

try this!!!

```
int numberEntered = 0;
    String entry = "";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
         entry = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("That is not an integer.  " +"Please try again.");
    }
    numberEntered = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print(numberEntered);
```